# Separation of variables Fourier constants integral

Tags: integration, partial-differential-equations, fourier-series

The question is as follows

\begin{align}
u_{tt} - u_{xx} &= 0, \quad 0 < x < \pi, t > 0 \\
u(x,0) &= \sin^3(x) \\ 
u_t(x,0) &= 0 \\
u(0,t) &= u(\pi,t) = 0
\end{align}

After following the standard algorithm, I get

$$E_m = \frac{2}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi}\sin^3(x)\sin(mx)dx$$

Now I know from the answer that the solution only exists from $m=1,3$. However, I don't know how to get the integral into a form to see this clearly.

Comment: Use a [trig identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Power-reduction_formulae) on $\sin^{3}(x)$.

Comment: Yes much easier thanks.